# Are questions regarding a "universal standard" on-topic here?

Tags: discussion, topic-scope, questions

A have a question that's along the lines of,

> Is there a universal standard that states the largest surround sound format a cinema/theatre should support?

Someone suggested asking it here, but, I want to check if this question (and others of the same category) are regarded as on-topic here.

Are they?

Answer (score 3):

I would think so, it is production and audio related.  If, for some reason, the community doesn't like it.  Then Video Production would also be a suitable place for it, but I personally would try asking it here first.

Answer (score 1):

I think it is on-topic. Not exactly sure what you're asking though, there are definitely minimum standards for things like THX certification (size, speakers etc), then there are maximum limits to how big a system can be scaled. You may just want to be more precise with what you are asking to get the best answer.